# 7" GPS with wince 6 cf 3.5 can't open com port

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce

i am using vb 2008 and the serialport object from the system.IO.Ports.SerialPort to connect to com2 serial port on my device to read data from the gps.But when i try to open the port windows troughs an IO Exception. My first thinking was that some other program is using the port but do be sure i tried to open the port with pocket-putty (COM2:) including the colon and  all functions and the gps data is flowing. In the documentation of the device the manufacturer writes this:

Pls note for GPS virtual serial port using, Data read not rely on the ComState. CbInQue, read serial data need to specify the length. To test the normal In the Sygic, Igo8, Careland map, detailed methods please use reference in CommTest ReadPortThread.

I don't understand what exactly he means.

My code functions on another Wince device but with wince 5.0 and CF 2.0

i am thankful for every answer

Comment: Show us the code used to open the port.  If pocket-putty can open it, then your app can too.

Answer (score 1):

Your port name is wrong.  Windows CE requires port names to be suffixed with a colon.  The exception message probably told you that the requested port name was not found.

Change the code to this:

```
mySerialPort.PortName = "COM2:"
```

Comment: ctacke: I tried "COM2:" it make's no different. I have attached a POS printer on port "COM4", this port can be opened just with "COM4" without the colon(in my software), in putty i always need to include the colon. Josef: i will try it out Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some device do not offer SerialPort access to GPS but a streamed access. Try to open the GPS port as file:

You may need this interop: http://code.google.com/p/win-mobile-code/source/browse/trunk/gps8/Gps8/GPS_Sample8/ReadFile.cs?r=89

and then try opening as file:

```
    #region CN50raw
    bgThread2 myStreamReaderThread;
    private void OpenStream()
    {
        //background thread already running?
        if (myStreamReaderThread == null)
        {
            string szPort="";
            szPort = GetGPSPort();
            if (szPort != "")
            {
                AddRawText("Start reading stream at '" + szPort +"'");
                //start a new thread
                myStreamReaderThread = new bgThread2(szPort);
                myStreamReaderThread.bgThread2Event += new bgThread2.bgThread2EventHandler(myStreamReaderThread_bgThread2Event);
            }
            else
                AddRawText("No raw GPS port found");
        }
    }

    private void OpenStream(string szPort)
    {
        //background thread already running?
        if (myStreamReaderThread == null)
        {
            if (szPort != "")
            {
                AddRawText("Start reading stream at '" + szPort + "'");
                //start a new thread
                myStreamReaderThread = new bgThread2(szPort);
                myStreamReaderThread.bgThread2Event += new bgThread2.bgThread2EventHandler(myStreamReaderThread_bgThread2Event);
            }
            else
                AddRawText("No raw GPS port found");
        }
    }
    void myStreamReaderThread_bgThread2Event(object sender, bgThread2.BgThreadEventArgs bte)
    {
        AddRawText(bte.sString);
    }
    private void CloseStream()
    {
        if (myStreamReaderThread != null)
        {
            myStreamReaderThread.Dispose();
            Application.DoEvents();
            myStreamReaderThread = null;
        }
        Application.DoEvents();
        mnuRAWStart.Enabled = true;
        mnuRAWStop.Enabled = false;
    }
    #endregion
```

the getGpsPort function above uses MS GPSID registry setting to find the raw port name. If your devcice does support GPSID, you do not need all the above and can use GPSID API to get location data of GPS.

Check your device's registry:

```
    private string GetGPSPort()
    {
        string szStr="";
        if (Registry.GetStringValue(Registry.HKLM,
                        "System\\CurrentControlSet\\GPS Intermediate Driver\\Multiplexer",
                        "DriverInterface",
                        ref szStr)
            == 0)
        {
            return szStr;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Registry.GetStringValue(Registry.HKLM,
                "System\\CurrentControlSet\\GPS Intermediate Driver\\Drivers",
                "CurrentDriver",
                ref szStr) == 0)
            {
                string szPath = "System\\CurrentControlSet\\GPS Intermediate Driver\\Drivers\\" + szStr;
                if (Registry.GetStringValue(Registry.HKLM, szPath, "CommPort", ref szStr) == 0)
                {
                    return szStr;
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

The above code lines are sources of my GpsSample application for Windows Mobile (Compact Framework)

Article: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/06/11/enhanced-gps-sample-update/

Code http://code.google.com/p/win-mobile-code/source/browse/trunk/gps8/Gps8/GPS_Sample8/?r=89